# When publishing Platform Events from Apex, is it possible to remove the "__c" suffix from the keys for custom fields?

Tags: platform-event

I need to match a client's schema. Is it possible to define my own Key values on a Platform Event that do not include the "__c" suffix?
I'm publishing from Apex in an Aura Component controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Platform Event fields are defined in the same manner as Custom Object fields and always receive the `__c` if they're custom.